# How to select entire row by a distinct field and sort the result by the COUNT that distinct field?

Tags: mysql, sql

My scenario is pretty similar to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463006/sql-select-entire-row-by-distinct-columns) but in addition to `Group By` [some field], I also need to sort the result by `COUNT`([some field]) .

for example, I may have this table:

```
 Title        Category
 Project 1    Admin
 Project 2    Development
 Project 2    Admin
 Project 3    Development
```

After applying this SQL statement:

```
SELECT Title, MIN(Category) AS Category
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Title
```

I have:

```
Project 1    Admin
Project 2    Admin
Project 3    Development
```

But I also need to sort this according to the `COUNT()` of Title to finally get this:

```
Project 2    Admin
Project 1    Admin
Project 3    Development
```

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Well, you simply do what you want: `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC`

Comment: @dnoeth, why does ORDER BY COUNT(*)   order by "Title" not "Category"?

Comment: It only orders by the count, a secondary order is random, unless you add it explicitly.

Comment: Go on. Try something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT` aggregate in `Order by`

```
SELECT Title, MIN(Category) AS Category
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Title
Order by count(*) desc,Category
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `count(Title)` in `order by`:

```
SELECT Title, MIN(Category) AS Category
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Title
ORDER BY count(Title) DESC, Title
```

Answer (score 1):

use `ORDER BY` clause with `COUNT` aggregate function

```
SELECT Title, MIN(Category) AS Category
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Title
Order by count(*) desc,Category
```

Comment: shall I ask why you used count(*) rather than count(Title)?